# Display subcategories in dropdown

Tags: categories, loop, blog

I have the following code on my website:

```
<div class="blog-cats drop">

<label class="custom-select">
<select class="styledSelect1" name="archive-dropdown" onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option value=""><?php echo attribute_escape(__('Select Month')); ?></option>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=option&show_post_count=1'); ?>     </select>
</label>

</div>
```

Instead of display posts by archive I want to display them by categories. BUT I am trying to get it so that it only show sub categories of a particular category called 'Blog'

Does anybody have any example of how I can go about achieving this?

Thanks for your help, it's appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar block of code to display the categories in a dropdown. I have picked the following example from WordPress codex article on [get_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories):

```
<select name="event-dropdown" onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> 
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select Event')); ?></option> 
    <?php 
    $categories = get_categories('child_of=10'); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $option = '<option value="/category/blog/'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
        $option .= $category->cat_name;
        $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
        $option .= '</option>';
        echo $option;
    }
    ?>
```

Most of the code is similar to the one you're using. The only things worth explaining are:

1. The `child_of=10` assumes your parent category has an id 10. You'll need to replace it with the real id of your category.
2. The `option value="/category/blog/` assumes that your permalinks are like this. If you have a different structure, you'll need to change it accordingly.

You can check out the article on [get_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) on **WordPress Codex** for more examples and options. For further **parameters** to pass to `get_categories($args)` array [refer to this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_category/#parameters) of the *WordPress Developer* documentation.